# Python Sightengine (API) - 'sightengine' has no attribute 'Client' Error

Tags: python, windows, automation

I am currently writing the code for an reddit scraper. I wanted to use Sightengine for scanning for inappropriate content within the downloaded videos. I have problems communicating with the api (I cant fully describe it), however - this is the cmd output that I cant fix and am stuck at:

```
File "C:\Users\Toni\Desktop\Redditvidscraper\redditvidscraper.py", line 14, in <module>
client = sightengine.Client(sightengine_user, sightengine_secret)
AttributeError: module 'sightengine' has no attribute 'Client'
```

This is my current code:

```
import sightengine
import os
import requests
import praw
import cv2
import subprocess


# Sightengine API credentials
sightengine_user = "CENSORED"
sightengine_secret = "CENSORED"

# Authenticate with Sightengine API
client = sightengine.Client(sightengine_user, sightengine_secret)


#SKIPPED CODE ----------------------------#

    
# Check if the video is shorter than 60 seconds
if duration < 60:
    print("mp4_lenght=shorter-60s_[codecontinued]")

    # Apply workflow on the video
    workflow_id = "CENSORED"
    video_path = "video.mp4"
    response = client.check('workflow', workflow_id, video_path)
    print("started_for_searching_unwanted_content")

        # Check if the video contains unwanted content
    if response['status'] == 'success' and response['media']['status'] == 'success':
        if response['media']['warnings']:
            print("mp4_content=unwanted")
        else:
            print("mp4_content=wanted")
    else:
        print("Error: ", response['status'])

else:
    print("mp4_lenght=longer-60s_[codestopped]")
    exit()
```

I tried virtual environments, updating all kind of packages, downloading + setting up SSL and as far as I am concerned this code has no logical or syntax errors its just the communication with this api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [github repository for sightengine](https://github.com/Sightengine/client-python) it says that you should do this to initialize the client:

```
from sightengine.client import SightengineClient
client = SightengineClient('{api_user}', '{api_secret}')
```

So in your case you would do this

```
from sightengine.client import SightengineClient
client = SightengineClient(sightengine_user, sightengine_secret)
```